# How to change column type in SQLAlchemy table?

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, firebird

I'm copying table from SQL Server to Firebird. I have a column of type BIT in SQL Server, but Firebird doesn't know this type. How can I change the type of the column to create table in my Firebird database?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# Get table from SQL Server
source_engine = create_engine(connection_url_source)
dest_engine = create_engine(connection_url_dest)
metadata = MetaData()
table = Table('my_table', metadata,  autoload=True, autoload_with=source_engine, schema='my_schema')
session = Session(source_engine)
query =session.query(table)
   
# Create table in firebird database
new_metadata = MetaData(bind=dest_engine)
columns = [Column(desc['name'], desc['type']) for desc in query.column_descriptions]
column_names = [desc['name'] for desc in query.column_descriptions]
table_new = Table("my_table", new_metadata, *columns)
table_new.create(dest_engine)
```

Here I receive the error:

> raise exception sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'my_table',
> column 'my_column'): Compiler <sqlalchemy_firebird.base.FBTypeCompiler
> object at 0x00000061ADAC8D60> can't render element of type BIT

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#metadata-reflection-dbagnostic-types

Comment: @GordThompson thank you very much! It's exactly what I was looking for. However, now I have another mysterious error. I would be very gratefull to you if you can help me.

When I try to write table with changed types to firebird via ```my_generic_table.create(dest_engine)``` I receive the error > ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -817\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -817\n- Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1', -817, 335544569)
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 my_column BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)

Comment: Are you using the [external dialect for Firebird](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-firebird/)?

Comment: Yes, I have this package installed and this is how my engine looks like ```dest_engine = create_engine(
    "firebird+fdb://%(user)s:%(pwd)s@%(host)s:%(port)d/%(path)s?charset=%(charset)s" % insert_params,
    encoding=insert_params['charset'])```

Comment: FWIW, [this code](https://pastebin.com/TMKjgej7) works for me.

Comment: I tried exactly your code, but it throws the same error. Anyway, thank you for help!

Comment: "Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database" might indicate that your script is connecting to the database as a user who does not have permission to CREATE TABLE.

Comment: I don't think that this is the case. I tried to create table with the code below and the same user and it was created.
`create_table=""" create table MY_TABLE (
                              id int not null primary key,
                              dt timestamp
                            ) """
statement_create = text(create_table)

with dest_engine.connect() as con:
       con.execute(statement_create)`

Comment: I ran my test code with sqlalchemy-firebird version 0.7.5 against Firebird version 3.0.5.33220. What versions are you using?

Comment: My sqlalchemy-firebird is of the same version as yours (0.7.5) and Firebird version is 2.5 (Is the information about the release important?)

BTW, I found this information in docs. However, I can't understand if it's aplicable to me, because I used sqlalchemy-firebird dialect https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/firebird.html#:~:text=The%20SQLAlchemy%20Firebird%20dialect%20detects%20these%20versions%20and%20adjusts%20its%20representation%20of%20SQL%20accordingly.%20However%2C%20support%20for%20dialect%201%20is%20not%20well%20tested%20and%20probably%20has%20incompatibilities.

Comment: It's probably important to note that I use reddatabase.

Comment: I just tested sqlalchemy-firebird 0.7.5 against Firebird 2.5.9 and [this code](https://pastebin.com/XQamQe96) works, so Red database may simply be sufficiently different from Firebird that the dialect won't work as-is.